# Using the Alias annotation when reading the managed objects

Tags: java, cumulocity

I want to extend the managed object with some custom fragments. Something like this:

```
@Alias(value = "Dictionary")
public class Dictionary extends AbstractDynamicProperties {
    private Map<String, String> records = new HashMap<>();

    @JSONProperty(ignoreIfNull = false)
    public Map<String, String> getRecords() { return this.records; }

    (...)
}
```

When I create a new managed object and save it into the inventory API everything looks great:

```
ManagedObjectRepresentation dictionary = new ManagedObjectRepresentation();
dictionary.setName(dictionaryName);
dictionary.set(new Dictionary());
```

Unfortunately, when I fetch this managed object and want to retrieve the Dictionary class I receive a HashMap:

```
dictionary.get(Dictionary.class).addRecord(key, value);
```

After some debugging, I founded that when a managed object is saved, **ExtensibilityConverter** (tryGetAlias() line 98) is iterating over all annotation in the object and if it finds the **Alias** annotation, it takes the value from there.

On the other hand, when the response from the Cumulocity is being deserialized, Svenson is using **AliasMapClassFinder** and I can see only initialization in the **ExtensibilityConverter**. I can't spot any place that this map **alias2ClassName** is filled and because it's always empty I receive the HashMap instead of the class I expect.

Am I missing something? Or this is a bug in the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with alias annotations. I assume you simply want to manage custom fragments in your Java application.

The easiest way to create a custom fragment and handle it in a type safe way is by simply creating a class that resembles your fragment.

Say you want to manage the following fragment:

```
{
    "my_custom_Fragment":{
        "stringProperty": "hello world",
        "numericProperty": 1337
    }
}
```

Then you create this class to resemble it:

```
package my.custom;

public class Fragment {
    private String stringProperty;
    private int numericProperty;

    //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

If you want to support dynamic properties, also extend `AbstractDynamicProperties` as in your example.

The fully qualified class name where dots are replaced with underscores will become the fragment name (in our example `my_custom_Fragment`) when you assign it to you managed object.

```
ManagedObjectRepresentation managedObject = new ManagedObjectRepresentation();
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
//set fragment properties
managedObject.set(fragment);
```

You can retrieve the fragment from your managed object in a type safe way as well.

```
ManagedObjectRepresentation created = inventoryApi.create(managedObject);
Fragment createdFragment = created.get(Fragment.class);
```

Comment: Hi, and this is exactly what I started to do. What I wanted to accomplish with the @alias annotation is to locate a class in module: my.custom.model.Fragment but to use fragment "my_custom_Fragment" and as I said, when I save the mo it's ok. Reading doesn't work, Svenson doesn't find the custom class.